# Angular- Chart.js, how off opacity in line chart?

Tags: chart.js

guys, how can i change opacity in line chart?? Look at my chart:

[image]

red, gray, and blue background. I need make it 100% invisible.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data2"                          chart-labels="labels2" chart-series="series2" chart-options="options2"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride2" chart-click="onClick" chart-colours="colours">
</canvas>
```

And fragment of JS:

```
$scope.rysujWykres2 = function (daneX, daneY, daneZ, daneA) { //metoda rysująca wykres
        $scope.labels2 = daneX;
        $scope.series2 = ['Ur', 'Ul', 'Uz'];
        $scope.data2 = [
            daneY,
            daneZ,
            daneA
        ];
        $scope.datasetOverride2 = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }];
        $scope.options2 = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                    id: 'y-axis-1',
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    position: 'left'
                }
                    ]
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 1
                }
            },
            colours: [{
                fillColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
                highlightFill: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
                highlightStroke: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)'
        }]
    };
}
```

but it doesnt work. Can u help me off this colours? I need only lines.

Comment: In your html should it be options2.colours instead of just colours?

Comment: Sorry u are right, but i was trying too other option, like a $scope.colours = ... but doesnt work

Comment: I see you're storing all your values in a function. Why not remove them from the function and just set the on $scope in your controller when the page loads?

Comment: On my website are 4 charts, they all are dynamic charts. They are working good, but just need change opacity, but i dont know how :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to see the fill under the line, then set the `fill` property to `false` (this is part of a [line chart dataset configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-dataset-structure)).  I'm not exactly sure how to do this in angular chart.js, but it looks like you could add it to your `datasetOverride2` object.

```
$scope.datasetOverride2 = [{fill: false}, {fill: false}, {fill: false}];
```

If this doesn't work then you need to use the property wherever you define each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

My friend,

```
$scope.datasetOverride2 = [{
  yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
  fill: false,
}];
```

work but only for blue color date, look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

aww, its so easy. Look:

[image]

Solution:

```
$scope.datasetOverride2 = [{fill: false},{fill: false},{fill: false}];
```

Thanks guys for help. We did it!